# SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>

Tags: laravel, gulp

When I ran the gulp command from the root of the project, a problem turned out.

```
elixir((mix) => {

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at execute (D:\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\index.js:24:18)
at Liftoff.handleArguments (D:\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:149:63)
at Liftoff.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_global\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:198:16)
```

The gulpfile is from a Laravel Project, here it is https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate/blob/master/gulpfile.js .
 I had searched the problem above over stack and other network station, but couldn't find any useful advise. 
 Btw, it was run on Windows, you can get it from the details code above.
 If somebody can help, I will be very appreciate . THX !

Comment: What does node -v and npm -v for you?

Comment: node: v0.12.3  npm: 2.9.1

Comment: Good, and what about `laravel-elixir` version(`package.json`)?

Comment: Try with update your node version with [LTS version](https://nodejs.org/en/), this may solved your problem.

Comment: laravel-elixir version(package.json): "^6.0.0-14", I will try to use LTS later.

Comment: Ok, Hope this should your solution

Comment: I made it, THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function are new JavaScript (ES6), so maybe your node and npm version is old and you should upgrade it. Use this official installer.

https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.9.2/node-v6.9.2-x64.msi

Comment: It works, I didn't uninstall the node first, but node works well. When I used gulp again, it showed me another problem that mergeConfig is not defined. I thought it might be caused by the old files, so I started over to install Laravel project. It is done. Thank you!